# How to configure organizing of Java imports in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, import, formatting

Currently Netbeans (I'm using version 7.3.1) has an in-built ability to organize imports in Java files via menu **Source » Organize Imports**. But I need to change the default order of imports. (For example, when working in a shared environment, software developers must use the same import settings.)

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

1. Click **Tools →  Options**.
2. Click the **Editor** icon.
3. Click the **Formatting** tab.
4. Set *Language* to: `Java`.
5. Set *Category* to: `Imports`.
6. Change the settings as desired.
7. Click **OK** or **Apply** to save the changes.

---

To organize the imports on save:

1. Click **Tools →  Options**.
2. Click the **Editor** icon.
3. Click the **On Save** tab.
4. Check **Remove Unused Imports**.
5. Check **Organize Imports**.
6. Click **OK** or **Apply** to save the changes.